# How to interpret (in Simple English) TypeScript's intersection type for array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have following TypeScript code snippet, in which I can interpret 3 constants declared (added explanation for them). For 4th one, I'm not able to interpret meaning of it in simple english.

```js
type Point = {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

type Loc = {
    lat: number;
    long: number;
}

// 1. Array contains values to be mix of either type
const coord1: (Point | Loc)[] = [{ x: 5, y: 10 }, {lat: 100, long: 50}];

// 2. Either Array of `Point` values or Array of `Loc` values
const coord2: Point[] | Loc[] = [{ x: 5, y: 10 }];

// 3. Array of object(s) created by merge of `Point` and `Loc` values
const coord3: (Point & Loc)[] = [{x: 5, y: 10, lat: 100, long: 50}];

// 4. ?
const coord4: Point[] & Loc[] = [{x: 5, y: 10, lat: 100, long: 50}];
```

Could someone please answer if 3 and 4 same, and if not, what could be an example to differentiate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248828/discussion-on-question-by-gourav-pokharkar-how-to-interpret-in-simple-english).